# How do I post SQL generated fields?

Tags: php, post, dynamically-generated

I am fairly new to php. I have a form set up where a user would make multiple selections from a list of items generated from a database; this list can be different lengths pending predetermined paths. In addition there are other fields before and after the generated section.

How would I go about getting the generated fields from the $_POST method?Is there any way to do something like $_POST['item' . $i]?

Here is a generated example:
global $dbc;

```
            $query="SELECT * FROM categories";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                    if($row > 0){


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="item' . $row['category_id'] . '" value="' . $row['category_id'] . '">' . $row['category_name'] . '<br></tr>';
```

}
echo '';

Comment: Can you show us how you are generating the form and clarify what values you need to extract

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output Dynamic Table Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676561/output-dynamic-table-data)

Comment: Please post sample code. We would be happy to help provided you give us enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something similar recently, I needed to collect an array of arrays of data of variable length that had been added to the DOM. I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but I ended up doing this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$obj) {
    if (preg_match('/^row\d+$/',$key)) {
        // some code to manipulate $obj
    }
}
```

[see more on preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

I had named each input in the table :

```
name="row"+i+"[fieldName]"
```

Again, I'm not sure if this is 'best practice', but it worked for my purposes. I hope it helps!

Comment: Just switched row to items in the preg_match and this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you had multiple form items that displayed dynamically from a database using the naming convention `item-$i`. (item-0,item-1,item-2,etc...), you could pull this dynamically from post using the following format...

`$_POST["item-$i"]`

Sometimes I pull everything out of POST and assign it to a variable through `foreach`.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $$key=$value;
}
```

That would create variables named $item-0, $item-1, $item-2, etc... To pull values from those, I would use variable variables `${"item-{$i}"}`.

[Variable Variables Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)